# JSTL remove white space between date

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, jsp-tags

i used to print time but i found white spaces between date hours and minutes, i used to format the time as follows:

```
<fmt:formatDate var="formtMins" pattern="m" type="TIME" timeStyle="default" value="${exam.to}" />
<fmt:formatDate var="formHours" pattern="h" type="TIME" timeStyle="default" value="${exam.to}" />
```

Given that: `exam.to` is a date object, i used to put additional zeros  if the minutes is zero or the hours is less than 10 as follows:

```
 <c:if test="${formtMins==0}">0</c:if>
    ${formtMins}:
    ${formHours}
<c:if test="${formHours<10}">0</c:if>
```

the previous code prints the time as follows:

```
12 : 0 0
0 4 :46
0 2 : 0 0
```

the spaces appears when i added the additional zeros and its not preferred, so i tried to remove any white space as follows but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
 <c:if test="${formtMins==0}">0${fnc:trim('')}</c:if>
  ${fnc:trim(formtMins)}:
  ${fnc:trim(formHours)}
<c:if test="${formHours<10}">0${fnc:trim('')}</c:if>
```

so the question is how to remove the this white spaces between the time?

Comment: I'm not sure if I would tag this as a Java question. No real Java code is involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the statements on a single line. The newline in JSP puts a space in HTML.

```
<c:if test="${formtMins==0}">0</c:if> ${formtMins}:${formHours} <c:if test="${formHours<10}">0</c:if>
```

Is not very nice but it works as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

on your JSP page, or

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

in your `web.xml` to configure white space trimming for all JSP pages.

This is kind of greedy. If you need a space after EL or a tag, you could use `${' '}`.